# Who is responsible for paying for an on-campus visit for a faculty interview?

Tags: interview, visiting

I am applying for faculty positions. I am worried that I may have to spend thousands of dollars for flights, hotel, and other transportation depending upon where I travel for the interview. I am wondering who is responsible for paying for an on-campus visit for a faculty interview? Is it the applicant or the employer?

Comment: In the US the university would reimburse travel expenses as a general rule.

Comment: In Germany or Austria it is likely to happen that applicant has to pay.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: really? On faculty level? I can see that happening if you are interviewing for a Ph.D. or postdoc position, but once you are applying for professorships, I would be surprised if the host institution did not cover reasonable travel expenses in Germany.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher My experiences with Austrian university systems were different. And everyone I know got reimbursed by German universities.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker Well, I have occasionbally seen job advertisements (maybe mostly W1 positions?) where they explicitly told applicants that they won't be reimbursed. In particular, I recall such an advertisement by Graz University because I was in the USA at that time (so I decided to not apply).

Comment: But what I actually meant to say by my comment is that the country _does_ matter.

Comment: Indeed. @Dr.Baje: what part of the world are we talking about?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think there are definitely universities that do not always have the funds for overseas flyouts (though I saw it, coincidently, at Graz). And interviews are often done online with few flyouts afterwards.

Comment: @Cag51, primarily US/Canada but I like to hear how practices and norms vary by country.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yeah, in Austria universities do *sometimes* expect candidates to travel on their own bill. But I think it's falling out of fashion, since it basically communicates "we expect every candidate to be a car / train ride away from us at most".

Comment: FWIW: in France, I have never, ever, seen travel expenses for a job interview reimbursed.

Comment: @IliaSmilga: Does the experience you describe include faculty interviews, or just other kinds of job interviews?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry: I meant faculty interviews. Outside of academia rules are different. I am currently trying (and have been trying for the past 8 years or so) to get a faculty position in France. (My field is pure math, in case it matters - but I do not think the situation is any different in other fields.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This may vary from place to place (country), but generally you should expect that the institution will cover the cost. Probably they won't cover first class travel or expensive hotels, but otherwise it is on them. Often they will make the arrangements themselves.

Another possibility is that you need to pay initially and make your own arrangements with reimbursement later - hopefully not too much later. Ideally in this situation you get a check when you leave, but that isn't always possible.

I would be wary of anywhere that won't cover travel. You should ask how and when you'll be reimbursed, but that might be in a conversation with the department head rather than the hiring committee. Practices vary.

International travel might present problems, however, so know before you get too deep into the process.

Comment: Thank you. I requests answers from other people too.

Comment: I would add that in some cases the university may have or at least impose strict budget limits on how much they can cover. So they do cover your travel cost but only under the assumption that this is a within country train ticket. If you need an international airplane ticket they may only pay a small fraction of the total cost.

Answer (score 3):

Academia and every non-academic employer usually pay for travel reimbursements to a job interview. There are several countries that have according laws. Nevertheless, not every small company or university obey. Some later try to only pay for the successful candidate and hope they don't get sued.

It is always better to ask for confirmation that the expenses are being covered and how the process is done before you spent too much money like for a plane ticket. If you don't get a clear answer, be prepared to pay it yourself or having to fight for the money, which might look bad on your application.

You could ask for an online interview first, to get an impression if the job offer is really that promising for you.

Comment: (Same question as I asked in response to someone else's comment on the original question) What is your experience with faculty hiring interviews? Every hiring committee I've served on has a first round of online interviews, followed by a smaller round of in-person interviews. Requesting an online interview is unlikely to change this process, and would hint that the candidate has not been mentored on the faculty job search process.

Comment: RLH:  Comments really shouldn't be used for asking new questions.  If you are interested in the process, I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I'm very familiar with the process. My question is asking the question answerer to clarify their qualification to answer the question, given that the last line of their answer suggests an unfamiliarity with the faculty hiring process.

Comment: @RLH Why is there a committee involved? Unless it is a tenure track, applying to a permanent position or guest lecturer is without a committee.

Comment: @usr1234567: What kind of faculty position are you envisioning that there's a sole person as opposed to a committee/team running the hiring process, and they're not already using a multi-stage screening process with online interviews to narrow down the pool before inviting candidates to campus?

Comment: _every non-academic employer usually pay for travel reimbursements to a job interview_ - Is this really true?  I was under the impression that non-academic employers are less likely to pay (for one, because they typically expect interviewees to be local).  But even in academia, things vary by country (if not other factors.)

Comment: Germany has a law (I am slightly paraphrasing) that says the employer pays unless they tell you *beforehand* they won't. Which they might well do, if they would have to fly you in from California.